# Can I use my unlimited Verizon data plan on my iPhone 5s and connect to my 2015 Cadillac Escalade Wi-Fi and AirPlay to my media center?

Tags: wifi, iphone, airplay

I have a 2015 Cadillac Escalade with the AT&T Wi-Fi 4G LTE system built in.
If I buy a data package streaming video only last about 20 minutes.
I have unlimited data on my iPhone 5s and want to know if I can connect to the Wi-Fi router inside the truck and AirPlay to the Apple TV I have hooked up to the entertainment system and use the data package on my phone or even my hotspot on my other iPhone to stream from my cellular connection but display to my Apple TV.

I have a jailbroken 5S dedicated to the truck; an Apple TV and XMBC box installed  that is connected to the media center. I also have two iPhone 5Ss which both have unlimited data and one with a hotspot package.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you use your Verizon on AT&T network wouldn't there  be roaming charges.

Answer (score 1):

You should confirm with Verizon, but the plans I've seen never have 'hotspot' capability on an unlimited plan.